# if sum of 2 numbers in the array are equal to another number (not in the array)

Tags: arrays, c, reverse

I am trying to write a program that picks up an array of 10-size numbers and another number. The program will check if there are two numbers in the array so that their sum is the same as a number that is not in the array.
If so, the program will print the 2 numbers, if not the program will print no.

This is what I did until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int array[10], number;
    for (int i; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &number);
}
```

I don't know how to continue from there. Can someone help, please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This program should fulfill your needs. It doesn't print a pair twice (e.g. `arr[1] + arr[2]` and `arr[2] + arr[1]`) and it doesn't accept the same number times two (e.g. `arr[3] + arr[3]`). I have included some comments in the code that help explain it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* set your own `sum` and `arr` */
    int sum = 14;
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 5, 7, 3, 9};
    /* calculate size of `arr` */
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        /* start from `i + 1` */
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) {
            /* check if the sum is right */
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == sum)
                printf("%d + %d = %d\n",
                       arr[i], arr[j], sum);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

With the above `sum` and `arr` the output of the program will be:

```sh
6 + 8 = 14
5 + 9 = 14
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem and you understand it, please mark it as accepted.